# Android app crashes on startup(Error inflating class android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, inflate-exception

I have followed the tutorial [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sPvCEsGm8us&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBsvRxJJOzG4r4k_zLKrnxl&index=30) and have made an Android app in Android studio. However, The app crashes on start up and I get this error:

```
03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main  03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity   ComponentInfo{com.test.test/com.test.test.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #43: Error inflating class android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView
```

I have tried many solutions which have worked for others but I am having no such luck. Is there any way to resolve this? If any code is needed then ask and i will post it. I have already tried the solutions provided [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26561235/error-inflating-class-android-support-v7-widget-toolbar),[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29045653/error-inflating-class-android-support-v7-internal-view-menu-actionmenuitemview)and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27331017/android-issue-with-inflateexception-error-inflating-class-android-support-v7-w) So, those solutions won't help.

Thanks in advance:)

**EDIT:**

Here is the main activity:

```
package com.test.test;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements topfrag.topfragListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public void createPic(String top, String bottom) {
   picfrag bfrag=(picfrag)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);
  bfrag.setPicText(top,bottom);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
}
```

**EDIT:**
Here is the `activity_main.xml` XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
>

<fragment
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    class="com.test.test.topfrag"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    tools:layout="@layout/topfrag" />

<fragment
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="320dp"
    class="com.test.test.picfrag"
    android:id="@+id/fragment2"
    tools:layout="@layout/picfrag"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT:**

Here are the other 2 xml files:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/koala"
android:id="@+id/picfragl">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text=" "
    android:id="@+id/toppictext"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text=" "
    android:id="@+id/bottompictext"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And the other xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/topfragl">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/toptext"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:width="350dp"
    />
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/bottomtext"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toptext"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:width="350dp"
    />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/okbutton"
    android:text="@string/okbutton_text"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bottomtext"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT:**

Here is the full log:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.test/com.test.test.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #43: Error inflating class android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2092)
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117)
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134)
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1218)
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #43: Error inflating class android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:357)
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:278)
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:252)
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.test.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5047)
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2056)
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1218) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:357) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:278) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:252) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.test.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5047) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2056) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1218) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.(LayerDrawable.java:85)
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.(LayerDrawable.java:67)
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintManager.getDrawable(TintManager.java:194)
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintManager.getDrawable(TintManager.java:167)
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawable(TintTypedArray.java:62)
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView.(ActionBarContextView.java:68)
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView.(ActionBarContextView.java:60)
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:357) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:278) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:252) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.test.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5047) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2056) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1218) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.597 27112-27112/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>   03-09 13:08:39.648 27112-27113/com.test.test D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 297K, 13% free 9461K/10759K, paused 13ms+20ms, total 69ms
>   03-09 13:08:39.648 27112-27112/com.test.test D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 49ms

Comment: It would help if you can post the complete logs.

Comment: add you gradle and activity also

Comment: Show your xml please

Comment: You have an error in your xml line 43. The xml you posted is shorter than 43 lines.

Comment: @barq which xml file should i post?

Comment: The one that contains the line where you are getting the error.

Comment: @barq It doesn't say which file has the error and all the xml fills i see have less than 43 lines.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, you followed a youtube video without having access to the author's source code? And in the video he is nowhere showing the `xml` for `activity_main.xml` or any other layout xml he is using. How on earth you managed to complete this course?

From his github I found the project in the video: https://github.com/buckyroberts/Source-Code-from-Tutorials/tree/master/Android_Beginners/023-030_DankMeme/java but it is missing all the resources (it has only the java classes).

Anyway for start I think in your `activity_main.xml` you are missing the closing tag of RelativeLayout in the end of the file: `</RelativeLayout>`. You IDE is not complaining about not closing it?

I suspect that even if you correct this, other errors will emerge. Try to find the complete source code of this course else follow another tutorial.

Comment: Downvoters please post a comment explaining the reasons. thanks

Comment: The video was the final video in a play list. He showed the entire project in those videos. Also, the /RelativeLayout is in my code, I just didn't select when i was posting it.

Comment: @Paul But the youtube link you posted did not contain it. Please be more specific in your question and provide valid data. There are two more layout `xml`s in the project, you could at least post them too!

Comment: I posted the other XML files. Sorry for the delay, My Internet stopped working for a bit. Thanks for your patience:)